# JSF passing in expression value into a commanButton

Tags: jsf

I am trying to access the value of the expression $result.id and use that value and pass it in the bean action commitBtn.  how do I go about doing this.

```
<c:forEach items="${bean.results}" var="result">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <b>Title:</b>
      ${result.id}
      <c:set var="Id" value="${result.id}" />
      <!-- this Id doesn't show as well, why -->
      <h:outputText value="#{Id}" binding="#{bean.Id_lbl}" id="iD_lbl" />

      <h:commandButton value="Commit" binding="#{bean.commitBtn}"
        id="commitBtn" action="#{bean.commitBtn}" />
    </legend>
...
```

Comment: Please see Markdown markup for displaying code: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Use the <f:param> tag to pass the value to the action.  Within the action you will have to get the param value from the requestMap

something like:

```
<h:commandButton blah blah blah>
   <f:param name="resultId" value="${result.id}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

then in action code:

```
resultId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("resultId");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `f:param` as some may suggest does **not** work in a `h:commandButton` in JSF 1.x. Use `f:setPropertyActionListener` instead:

```
<h:commandButton value="Commit" binding="#{bean.commitBtn}" id="commitBtn" action="#{bean.commitBtn}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.resultId}" value="#{result.id}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Also see [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) for more hints.